# Is there any way to deploy KEDA helm chart into K8s with terraform?

Tags: terraform, devops, kubernetes-helm, infrastructure-as-code, keda

I want to deploy KEDA autoscaler Helm Chart into a Kubernetes cluster installed locally (kind) using Terraform but I can't seem to find any helm releases related online..
I'm seeking your help, ty!

Tried to look for keda autoscaler helm chart

Comment: You are talking about KEDA autoscaler?

Comment: yes, KEDA autoscaler

Answer (score 0):

The helm charts are here:

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/kedacore/keda

The installation can be done by:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = ">= 2.12.1"
    }
  }

  required_version = "~> 1.6"
}

resource "helm_release" "keda" {
  name = "keda"

  repository       = "https://kedacore.github.io/charts"
  chart            = "keda"
  namespace        = "keda"
  version          = "2.12.1"
  create_namespace = true
}
```

After applying you should see sth like below:

```
kubectl get pods -n keda
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
keda-admission-webhooks-68b4cfbb48-7z7w8           1/1     Running   0               2m22s
keda-operator-647b44c8bb-wjb6g                     1/1     Running   1 (2m15s ago)   2m22s
keda-operator-metrics-apiserver-5f945dc9f8-f7529   1/1     Running   0               2m22s
```